# Sending Arabic text email is not working

Tags: php

I am using this code for user forgot password email . but its not giving me the actual output . after submiting the form it brings arabic result and html tags aswell. I am receving html tags too in my mail
code:

```
//......mail
  $to = $email;
   $subject = 'Forgot Password';
   $message = '
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
   <title>هل نسيت كلمة المرور</title>
   </head>
   <body dir="rtl">



   </p>
  <p align="right">عزيزي،</p>
   <p align="right">لقد تلقينا طلبا من جانبكم لاستعادة كلمة المرور. </p>
   <p align="right">يتم إلحاق بيانات الدخول الخاصة بك أدناه: </p>
   <p align="right">البريد الإلكتروني:  <strong>'.$to.'</strong></p>
   <p align="right"> 
  كلمة المرور:<strong> '.$password.'</strong><br/>
  إلى تسجيل الدخول الرجاء اضغط هنا أو نسخ www.cb.gminns.com/login.php الرابط ولصقه في شريط عنوان المتصفح الخاص بك.

   </p>
   <br>
   <p align="right"> Warm Regards,
Contributors Den Team  </p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ';
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";


   $headers .= 'From: Contributors Den <noreply@test.com>' . "\r\n";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('location:forgot_password.php?msg=sent');
```

and the output is giving me like this in my yahoo mail web version ,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>هل نسيت كلمة المرور</title>
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">



  </p>
  <p align="right">عزيزي،</p>
  <p align="right">لقد تلقينا طلبا من جانبكم لاستعادة كلمة المرور. </p>
  <p align="right">يتم إلحاق بيانات الدخول الخاصة بك أدناه: </p>
  <p align="right">البريد الإلكتروني:  <strong>admintest@yahoo.com</strong></p>
  <p align="right"> 
  كلمة المرور:<strong> 123</strong><br/>
  إلى تسجيل الدخول الرجاء اضغط هنا أو نسخ  الرابط ولصقه في شريط عنوان المتصفح الخاص بك.

  </p>

  </body>
  </html>
```

this is the final email I have received and it brings result with html coding

Comment: Your problem description is not entirely clear. What problem are you facing?

Comment: after submiting the form it brings arabic result and html tags aswell. I am receving html tags too in my mail

Comment: Try putting the `$message` value in double quotes `"---html text---"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue :

```
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

This should be

```
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Comment: problem has been solved by putting this 
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
thank you